# Проигрывание YouTube video без использования YouTube Data API

Tags: java, android, youtube

Хочу добавить в приложение возможность поиска и просмотра,видео на `YouTube` без использования `YouTube Data API` так как там есть ограничения по количеству запросов.

Интересует как это реализовано в `Telegram` [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробывал делать через `WebView` как показано в [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768837/playing-html5-video-on-fullscreen-in-android-webview/16179544#16179544) и еще несколько похожих ответов, но у меня вместо проигрывания видео в своем `WebView` почему то открывается приложение `YouTube`.

Или открывается в `WebView` но нету кнопки сделать на весь экран, в `Telegram` это все ревализовано, и судя по всему они тоже не использую `YouTube API`.

Вопрос, как можно реализовать подобный функционал  у себя в приложении?

Comment: JFYI: https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram

Comment: @post_zeew   мне эта ссылка ни о чем не сказала, как она относится к решению мой проблемы?

Comment: Это исходники Telegram.

Comment: @post_zeew Понял, спасибо, буду разбиратся!)

Comment: @post_zeew Исходники кратко посмотрел, там документации нету - трудно читаются + там много такого что мне не нужно!

Может знаете решение попроще?

Comment: Нет, я с этим особо не работал.